# How to create new column names and populate row values from lists in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a data set that contains a list of values in two columns. I need values from lists in column A to become new column names and values from lists in column B to become corresponding row values.

My dataset looks like this:

```
              A                       B  
----------------------------------------------------                  
0   [alpha, alpha2, alpha3]  [betha, betha2, betha3]     
1   [alpha, alpha2, alpha3]  [betha, betha2, betha3]
2   [alpha, alpha3]          [betha, betha3]
```

I need to get dataset that look like this one:

```
      alpha    alpha2    alpha3
------------------------------- 
0     betha    betha2    betha3
1     betha    betha2    betha3
2     betha    None      betha3
```

Appreciate help, i am running out of ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `DataFrame` prohibitively large?

Comment: Assuming the length of both df's are equal, you could iterate over the rows to create new dataframes using each row's values, and then combine them together using an outer merge.

Comment: @ ALollz My dataframe contains about 300000 rows

Comment: why does betha3 go into the 3rd column and not the 2nd in the final row?

Comment: @Datanovice Because there is no corresponding value for betha2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pairs of lists are always the same length: `explode` (pandas 0.25+) + `pivot`. With different lengths, you can add a `cumcount` level after the explode (`groupby(level=0).cumcount()`) to the index so that they will align, though you'll need to make decisions about what alignment means in that case.

```
df1 = (pd.concat([df.explode(x)[x] for x in ['A', 'B']], 1)
         .pivot(columns='A', values='B')
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

   alpha  alpha2  alpha3
0  betha  betha2  betha3
1  betha  betha2  betha3
2  betha     NaN  betha3
```

Comment: This solution works well and fast. Thank You @ALollz

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([('alpha', 'alpha2', 'alpha3'),('alpha', 'alpha2', 'alpha3'),('alpha', 'alpha3')])
B = pd.DataFrame([('betha', 'betha2', 'betha3'),('betha', 'betha2', 'betha3'),('betha', 'betha3')])

final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.unique(A.values.ravel()))

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    col = list(A.iloc[i])
    data = list(B.iloc[i])
    row_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)
    row_df.loc[0] = data
    final_df = final_df.append(row_df,sort=False)

final_df.dropna(axis=1,how='all', inplace=True)
print(final_df)
```

Output is as follows:

```
   alpha  alpha2  alpha3
0  betha  betha2  betha3
0  betha  betha2  betha3
0  betha     NaN  betha3
```

Comment: Elements in A and  B columns are lists, not tuples. This solution works for tuples and not for lists.